# pressing a UITabBar button Programmatically in Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

i used the code below to make a UITabBarController :

inside `AppDelegate.h`:

```
    IBOutlet UITabBarController *rootController;
...
    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *rootController;
```

inside AppDelegate.m

```
@synthesize rootController;

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [self.window addSubview:rootController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Now i need to know how to implement this method inside AppDelegate:

```
- (void)SwitchToTab:(int)index{
    //go to tabview 1 or 2 ...
    }
```

Comment: have you try with
[rootController setSelectedItem:[rootController.items objectAtIndex:index]]; ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
self.rootController.selectedIndex = 2; // or whatever index you like
```

or this:

```
self.rootController.selectedViewController = oneOfTheViewControllersInTheTabController;
```

See the [UITabBarController reference page](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for details.